# Is it possible to open Lektor admin interface in production/deployed mode?

Tags: lektor

I want to allow content creators access to admin page and let them create and edit blog posts. This as far as I know is currently only possible if Lektor is running in development mode - then one can open admin end edit in CMS.

Is there any way someone can manage blog without running their own instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are asking for defies the purpose of a static site generator. Lektor explicitly generates static content so that you do not have to host a CMS.
That being said, you can host the development mode on your server to allow editing. Though I am not sure what the limits are, especially on concurrent use. And you want to add an authentication layer to prevent unauthorized users from editing your website.

TLDR: no, you can not. You have to run a dev server instance.